# How are scripted camera usually managed?

Tags: camera, character

I noticed that many open games (think platformers, adventure, action...) have very complex cameras that appear to mix both automatic placement most of the time, and sort of pre-placed camera locations.

How are these usually implemented? Is it just some sort of zone trigger that then launches an interpolation between the last camera state and the scripted camera for the zone, or are there more special details?

Comment: Here's an interesting dissection of the camera in SMB3.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCIMPYM0AQg

Comment: Well I was more thinking of complex 3D scenes. 2D cameras can be automated since there aren't much angle view problems.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can accomplish it.  One way would be to use screen fade techniques to transition between the camera location swaps (current camera position & the camera track start/end positions) so that it blends nicely, which is generally great for cut scene type scenarios.

The other option would be to do as you described, interpolate from the camera's current position to the first camera track sequence node and applying some focal point so that the camera twists & spins as desired over the interpolation.  Then begin the camera track sequence and when it ends, repeat the interpolation for the camera from the last track sequence node back to the camera's original position when the trigger was activated.